# Excel formula to find frequency of occurrence of unique words in a column

Tags: spreadsheet, microsoft-excel-2010

I have  a spreadsheet with a column with repeating number of different kinds of words like

```
A1
A2
A3
A1
AA
A2
A7
A8
A1
```

Now I want to plot a graph showing the frequency of occurrences of a word. The words are different but the re-occur quite often. Just using the [countif](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx) is not helpful because then I have to manually specify the criteria of each word in the formula. Since the number of words are large, I want the words to be each auto-filled in the criteria.
Can someone suggest a formula for this?

Comment: Do you want to specify for what words to search? - Or does this have to work dynamically.

Comment: Just clarified that in the question. Its hard to specify the word manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your data a name in the first row, let's call it Word.

Create a pivot table with:

`Row labels: Word`

`Values: Count of Word`

Then go to the `Value Field Settings` for `Count of Word` and set `Show Values As` to `% of Grand Total`.

Results:

```
Row Labels    Count of Word
A1            33.33%
A2            22.22%
A3            11.11%
A7            11.11%
A8            11.11%
AA            11.11%
Grand Total  100.00%
```

You can then add a pivot chart if you wish.

Tested in Excel 2010.

Note: You could also do this using Histogram in Data Analysis but if your data is likely to change/grow then pivot tables are easier to update.

Comment: Is there an answer to this question that works for Excel 2013? I cannot see 'Row labels' and 'Values' to specify for Excel 2013.

Comment: @TolaOdejayi, I don't have access to Excel 2013 but in Excel for Office 365 the field areas are now called 'Rows' and 'Values.'