# Produce counts of repeating items in column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a column like this:

```
A
-------
Angelos
Angelos
Angelos
Dukas
Dukas
Komnenos
Komnenos
Komnenos
Komnenos
Laskaris
Laskaris
Palaiologos
Palaiologos
Palaiologos
Palaiologos
Palaiologos
Palaiologos
```

I would like to convert this into a table like this:

```
A           B
-------     -
Angelos     3
Dukas       2
Komnenos    4
Laskaris    2
Palaiologos 6
```

In other words, in the first column, there should be each repeating item, and in the second column, there should be the number of times that the column repeats.

Is there a single formula or command that can do this? Or do I have to have a complicated COUNTIF / SUM forumla?

I tried following the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/284078/excel-formula-to-find-frequency-of-occurrence-of-unique-words-in-a-column), but it didn't work for me - I could not see where to specify 'Row labels' and 'Values'. This could be because I am using Excel 2013, and that answer relates to Excel 2010.

Comment: This is **exactly** what a pivot table is designed to do.  Read a bit more about them and you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use two new columns. Copy your column of names into a new column.
Select the new column, go to the data tab, and select "Remove duplicates".
Then in the next column, you simple use a `=COUNTIF()`, like in the following example:
[image]

And just drag it down to match column `B`.

To actually "convert" you example column `A`to the new column `A` and `B` while removing the original column `A` you definitely need a macro.
Formulas can't remove things from other cells, and if you cut all the duplicates, there's nothing for the `B` column to count.

You could produce the result by hiding rows, `COUNTIF` would still count the hidden words. But the process would still have to be done by hand or macro.

Comment: I disagree that this is the easiest way. A Pivot Table seems far easier to me.

Comment: @AdamV That's probably true. I will have to blame my lack of experience with pivot tables.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I was able to solve the problem by using a pivot table.

After creating the table, I selected the column with the values that I wanted counted, then I dragged the column to both the 'Rows' and 'Values' sections; the value in the 'Values' section then became a 'Count of' the column, and it had all the counts that I wanted.